# Extract the elements not in common between two different point sources

Tags: qgis, extract

I've downloaded accommodations from two different sources, now I have the list of elements from them in two separated shape files and also the list of elements in common between these two sources. How can I extract the elements from the attribute table that are only in the first source and not in the second and viceversa? I need something like a difference between two point vectors.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

just go to arc gis and goto data management tools--->general--->merge.just add the 2 shapefiles u have and display the attribute table there u find the both data merged as you asked.and export the data and use in qgis as you tagged.

Comment: Well, i don´t know why ArcGis is needed here as the same option is available in Qgis as well (as it is tagged in the question). It is found at Vector-Geoprocessing-Merge.

Comment: @Matte I think you should add a new answer so that the asker has the option of accepting an answer which directly addresses their question.

Comment: I think we need to keep in mind what tags the questioner has used so that answers are a little more related.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answer that you should use ArcGis, which is maybe not appropriate as you where looking for a Qgis solution you can use the same option there that can be found under

Vector-Geoprocessing-Merge

and leads to your desired output also in this Software.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but I guess the tool needed is actually not Merge but Symmetrical Difference.

Comment: Possible as well, but i understood it the way that the attribut table should contain only  the indication of  the origin of the feature. With symmetrical differnce you would change the geometry.